# Create downloadable link and Preview File for OneDrive DriveItem

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I've been trying to generate a public downloadable URL for OneDrive
 for Business and SharePoint DriveItem object using `/createLink` [api](https://github.com/OneDrive/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createlink.md).

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  -d '{"type":"view","scope":"anonymous"}' \
  -H 'Authorization: bearer xxx_Access_Token_xxx' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/<item-id>/createLink"
```

Above call returns JSON result with **body.link.webUrl** (`https://my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/XXXXrKmGKlXXXXXXXXXXsq0Bh3x4TTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`) being the sharable URL. However, this link doesn't contain the reference to file directly.

As per [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/OneDrive-for-Business/Get-direct-download-link-of-a-file-in-OneDrive-for-Business/m-p/149888/highlight/true#M3271) comment, appending `download=1` as query string parameter to generated shared URL will allow the user to open the original file directly. But I could not find any documentation supporting this behavior.

Is it possible to

- Download the file directly.
- To use public URL as `src` attribute of `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow official document of [OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink?view=odsp-graph-online)

You will have to put below line of code in success field of IProgressCallback. Here **ItemId** is "*id of uploaded item*".

```
String itemId = result.id;
            TestBase testBase = new TestBase(xdata.getinstance().getSetting(config.onedriveaccesstoken));
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  downloadfileonedrive = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
                    com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.Permission response = testBase.graphClient
                        .me()
                        .drive()
                        .items(itemId)
                        .createLink("edit", "anonymous")
                        .buildRequest().post();        
                     Log.e("Sharable link : ", ""+response);     

                     try {

                          String sharabalelink = new JSONObject(response.getRawObject().getAsJsonObject("link").toString()).getString("webUrl");

                      } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                 super.onCancelled();
            }};
            downloadfileonedrive.execute();
```